# node.js require modules at different git tag points

Tags: git, node.js

I am developing a node.js express app along with several private node_modules.

I would like to be to expose my users to different versions of these modules by using git tags. Is this a sensible idea, and is there an equally sensible way of doing this by auto-detecting the tags, and requiring the modules at each of those git tag references?

Perhaps something like 'git-helpers' might exist? (code is coffeescript)

```
git = require('git-helpers?').dir('./node_modules/module/')
tags = git.getGitTags()

modules = []

for tag in tags
  git.requireAtGitTag tag, (err, res) ->
    modules.push {version: tag, module: res}
```

then modules variable would look something like this

```
[
 { version: "0.8", module: required_module_here_at_tag},
 { version: "0.9", module: required_module_here_at_tag},
 { version: "1.0", module: required_module_here_at_tag}
]
```

**Edit**

I have come up with an idea using a node.js git cli wrapper called [Gift](https://github.com/sentientwaffle/gift). Is this a sensible way of doing it?

```
gift = require("gift")
repo = gift("./node_modules/moduleA")

modules = []

repo.tags (err, tags) ->
  for tag in tags
    repo.checkout tag.name, (err, a) ->
      modules.push
        version: tag.name
        module: require("./node_modules/moduleA")
```

Answer (score 1):

the best way to archieve something like this is to use npm: [Git URLs as Dependencies](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#Git-URLs-as-Dependencies)

example `package.json` in your app folder:

```
{
  "name": "foobar",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "library": "git://example.com/user/project.git#tag_name"
  }
}
```

you can then:

```
var library = require('library')
```

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't overlooked this option. Its not quite right for me as it requires me to keep having to update my dependencies whenever a tag is added. I would also need to update the code inside the app so it knows to require the new tag. And while this probably wouldn't be a problem if this was one module, I have loads of modules each needing to expose their tagged versions. I hope this makes sense!

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question :) by the way I don't see a practical way to achieve what you need, perhaps a simple CDN-like directory structure will do (like what [cdnjs](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs.git) does).